# alter localstrorage and view modifications in DOM

Tags: dom

If I modify the webappsstore.sqlite file (for example, in a Firefox scenario), adding manually a row with a custom key/value data and making the scope google.com, is it possible that I see this data in the localstorage of the page, when I visit google.com site ?

Currently, if I visit a site, the webappstore.sqlite is not updated: I see data in the Dev tool but if I open the webappsstore file with DBBrowser for SQlite, I don't see those data. Are they in RAM ? Aren't they written immediately in the file ?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox changed something in last years so I found out that:

1. LocalStorage is managed by data.sqlite file in /.mozilla/firefox/xxxxx.default-release/storage/default/https+++yyyyy.com/ls/
   where xxxxx is a random name and yyyyy is the site domain.
2. you can modify it using DB Browser for example and get the value in Firefox